# REST Api to filter items from sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I need to filter data two times, once using current user and then by date. So I have used below rest API..

```
 url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('LateLogin')/items?$select=Author/Title,Duration,Date,Created&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/Title eq 'Vikash Kumar'&Created ge '2015-10-15' & Created le '2015-10-20'&@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
```

but it is filtering only current user records and not by date....

Comment: Really your accepted solution worked for you? I got error while running it?

The expression "$filter=(Author/Title eq 'Vikash Kumar') and ((Created ge '2015-10-15') and (Created le '2015-10-20'))" is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try below line of code?

```
 url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('LateLogin')/items?$select=Author/Title,Duration,Date,Created&$expand=Author&$filter=(Author/Title eq 'Vikash Kumar') and ((Created ge '2015-10-15') and (Created le '2015-10-20'))&@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
```

Comment: Really? It worked? How? I am getting error while running this!!!

Comment: "$filter=(Author/Title eq 'Vikash Kumar') and ((Created ge '2015-10-15') and (Created le '2015-10-20'))" is not valid

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems in your current `URL`

use `and` instead of `&` inside the `$filter`

Before using `DateTime` in $filter, you have to convert it into `toISOString()`. So do it like following

```
var startDate = new Date("2015-10-15");
var endDate = new Date("2015-10-20");
```

Now use above dates in your `URL`

```
url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('LateLogin')/items?$select=Author/Title,Duration,Date,Created&$expand=Author&$filter=Author/Title eq 'Vikash Kumar' and Created ge "+ startDate.toISOString() +" and Created le "+ endDate.toISOString() +"&@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
```